# href link is removed due to JQuery Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have the following table which expands / collapses when I click the header.  However the links within the table rows are removed no matter how many times I add them back.  Below is my html for my table:

```
<table border="0">
       <tbody>
          <tr class="header">
             <td>Header</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 3 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 4 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 5 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="header">
             <td>Header</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 3 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 4 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 5 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="header">
             <td>Header</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 3 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 4 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Data Row 5 Goes Here...</td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Here is my script:

```
<script
$(document).ready(function() 
  { 
    $('.RowToClick').click(function () 
       { 
         $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function() 
            { 
              if ($(this).is('.row')) 
                { return false; 
                } 
              $(this).toggle(350); 
            }; 
       ); 
   );
</script>
```

Comment: Why are my links being removed?

Comment: From the code you've shared I cannot see any problem, is it somewhere else in your code?

Comment: your jquery code targets classes I do not see in your html

Comment: @Rhys Bradbury  I don't see anything wrong with the code as well but when I put the code into SharePoint...it wipes out my URLs.

Comment: This could be share point, I found this ref https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-hyperlink-to-a-Data-View-728fb35d-5e1d-403f-bd5f-86d55aad30b4